# The Doppler Effect in tkinter and matplotlib graph

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tkinter, pyaudio

I need help with going about one code that I've been having problems executing. I'm graphing a sine wave that's tied to a pyaudio stream and I want to show a Doppler effect on both. I want to show the initial wave, then the Doppler effect, and then revert back to the original wave. I also want to loop this event to a button. There's 2 other floats in the program from entries of the GUI. Problem is I genuinely don't know where to start. I've tried making it a piece wise function where a new variable will be changed for that range and then I tried the formula to change. I don't know if there's a program that will make it easier in the long run? Or a method I haven't tried. All help is welcome.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Label, Button, Entry, TOP, BOTH
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import pyaudio
DEFAULT_Z = 1
back_up=4
DEFAULT_FREQUENCY = 220
DEFAULT_DURATION = 5
VOLUME = 0.3
INTERVAL = 100

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("SHM Simulation - Testing")

        label = tk.Label(self.root, text="SHM Simulation")
        label.pack()

        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=root)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1)
        self.ax.set_xlim(-0.1, (2 * np.pi + 0.1)/10)

        self.quit_button = Button(master=self.root, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
        self.quit_button.pack(side='right')

        self.sound_button = Button(self.root, text='Sound off', command=self.toggle_sound)
        self.sound_button.pack(side='right')

        self.plot_button = Button(self.root, text='Start')
        self.plot_button.pack(side='right')
        self.plot_button.bind('<Button-1>', self.on_click)

        self.dopp= Button(self.root, text='Doppler')
        self.dopp.pack(side='right')
        self.dopp.bind('<Button-1>', self.wow)


        tk.Label(self.root, text='Frequency').pack(side='left')
        self.frequency_entry = Entry(self.root)
        self.frequency_entry.insert(0, DEFAULT_FREQUENCY)
        self.frequency_entry.pack(side='left')

        tk.Label(self.root, text='Duration').pack(side='left')
        self.duration_entry = Entry(self.root)
        self.duration_entry.insert(0, DEFAULT_DURATION)
        self.duration_entry.pack(side='left')
        self.ani = None
        self.running = False
        self.audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.sound = False
        self.samples = np.array([])
        self.xdata = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, 0.0001)



    def quit(self):
        self.audio.terminate()
        self.root.quit()

    def get_data(self, frame):
        self.ydata = np.sin((self.frequency* self.z * self.xdata) + frame)
    def update_frame(self, frame):
        self.get_data(frame)
        self.line.set_data(self.xdata, self.ydata)

        if frame > self.duration - 1.1 * INTERVAL / 1000 :
            self.ani = None
            self.running = False
            self.plot_button.config(text='Start')
            self.dopp.config(text='Doppler')


        return self.line,

    def start_animation(self):
        self.xdata = []
        self.ydata = []
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(self.xdata, self.ydata, lw=.5)

        self.xdata = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, 0.0001)

        duration_range = np.arange(0, self.duration, INTERVAL / 1000)
        self.ani = FuncAnimation(self.fig,
                                 self.update_frame,
                                 frames=duration_range,
                                 interval=INTERVAL,
                                 repeat=False)

        if self.sound:
            ''' start audio in a seperate thread as otherwise audio and
                plot will not be at the same time
            '''
            x = threading.Thread(target=self.play_sound)
            x.start()

    def callback(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
        out = self.samples[:frame_count]
        self.samples = self.samples[frame_count:]
        return (out*VOLUME, pyaudio.paContinue)

    def play_sound(self):

        fs = 44100
        self.samples = (np.sin(2 * np.pi * self.z *np.arange(fs * self.duration) *
                        self.frequency / fs)).astype(np.float32)

        stream = self.audio.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                                 channels=1,
                                 rate=fs,
                                 output=True,
                                 stream_callback=self.callback)

        stream.start_stream()

        # pause audio when self.running is False
        while stream.is_active():
            while not self.running:
                if stream.is_active:
                    stream.stop_stream()
                else:
                    pass
            if self.running and not stream.is_active():
                stream.start_stream()
            else:
                pass

        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()

    def toggle_sound(self):
        if self.sound:
            self.sound_button.configure(text='Sound Off')
        else:
            self.sound_button.configure(text='Sound On ')

        self.sound = not self.sound




            except ValueError:
                self.frequency = DEFAULT_FREQUENCY
                self.frequency_entry.insert(0, DEFAULT_FREQUENCY)
                self.duration = DEFAULT_DURATION
                self.duration_entry.insert(0, DEFAULT_DURATION)
                self.z= DEFAULT_Z


            self.start_animation()
            self.running = True

            print('animation started ...')
            return

        if self.running:
             self.ani.event_source.stop()
             self.dopp.config(text='Doppler!')

        else:
             self.ani.event_source.start()
             self.dopp.config(text='Pause')

        self.running = not self.running


    def on_click(self, event):
        if self.ani is None:
            try:
                self.ax.lines.pop(0)
            except IndexError:
                pass

            try:
                self.frequency = int(self.frequency_entry.get())
                self.duration = int(self.duration_entry.get())



            except ValueError:
                self.frequency = DEFAULT_FREQUENCY
                self.frequency_entry.insert(0, DEFAULT_FREQUENCY)
                self.duration = DEFAULT_DURATION
                self.duration_entry.insert(0, DEFAULT_DURATION)



            self.start_animation()
            self.running = True
            self.plot_button.config(text='Pause')
            print('animation started ...')
            return

        if self.running:
             self.ani.event_source.stop()
             self.dopp.config(text='Doppler')

        else:
             self.ani.event_source.start()
             self.dopp.config(text='Pause')

        self.running = not self.running

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks.

Comment: first off show your code then explain the probem you have with it i.e. what it is doing compared to what it should be doing.

Comment: @DrBwts Sorry, there it is!

Comment: So I decided to settle on a scale. But now my problem lies in updating the animation and sound when the scale is changed.

Comment: Is this a minimal verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Spinor8, I meant it more as the complete scenario, some bits are changed, and I haven't added the Scale to the code above. But I wanted for others to be able to see functions that I'd be unable to use from my code set-up. It is long, but I wanted to be clear.